# How do I achieve uniqueConstraint and map in separate table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

```
@Entity
class Employee {
  @Column
  private UUID id;

  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column
  private String lastName;  

}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Department {
  @Column
  private UUID id;

  @Column
  private List<Employee> employees;  
}
```

- I want to have a separate table which has **OneToMany** relation of department with employees like  **DepartmentEmployee**

---

```
--------------------------
departmentId | EmployeeId
--------------------------
      1      |     1     |
      1      |     2     |
      1      |     3     |
      2      |     5     |
--------------------------
```

- I want to make sure that there is a `uniqueConstraint` on `Department.id` and `Employee.id`

How do I achieve this in `JPA`?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `@OneToMany` on `employees` with `@JoinTable` annotaion.

Something like,

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="DEPT_EMP", 
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="departmentId"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EmployeeId"))
private List<Employee> employees;
```

Hope you don't need to worry about the unique constraint here, It is by default creates one. However you want to provide specific name, You can make use of `uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint` propery of `JoinTable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `@JoinTable`, with `uniqueConstraints`:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
    @Column
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;
}

@Entity
class Department {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumn(name = "department_id"),
        uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"employee_id", "department_id"}))
    private List<Employee> employees;  
}
```

*Caveat: The above is pseudocode only.*